# django session.objects.filter gives static data

Tags: python, django

I have been debugging this half a day now... anybody have ideas?

I wrote a python script to monitor active sessions, found this:

```
sessions = Session.objects.filter(expire_date__gte=datetime.now())
for session in sessions:
    data = session.get_decoded()
    id = data.get('_auth_user_id', None)
    ses = session.session_key
    if id:
        name = User.objects.get(id=id)
```

gives nice list... ok. But -- if user logs out or in, the above code does not reflect the change. It just keeps repeating the original, outdated list.

Is there a caching issue? Think not -- disabled memcached, and no change.
Tried file and memcache based session storage -- strange result: the code above seems to read db-based session storage.

So, I suspect the initialization is not correct for the 1.4.3 -- as there seem to have been various ways to initialize environment. I believe 1.4. does not require anything but the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE to be set to the app.

Next, if this does not resolve.. must use file based session storage and poll the directory.. that seems to be alive and kicking in realtime :)

Comment: Where is this code, exactly?

Comment: it's just a standalone python script with these imports: 
`from django.contrib.auth.models import User` and
`from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session`

Comment: OK. How is it repeating? Is there an outer loop around the code you've shown, or is the entire script repeatedly triggered, eg by a cron?

Comment: yep -- repeated in few seconds intevals. the point is that during the same execution, the data stays same. But if stopped and rerun -- new and correct data appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is caused by transaction isolation. By default, each connection to the db runs inside a transaction. Usually, that equates to a view, and the transaction middleware takes care of opening and closing the transaction. In a standalone script, you'll need to [manage that yourself](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/db/transactions/).

Comment: Yes, this was it. Added `from django.db import transaction` and `@transaction.commit_on_success` decorator and finally `transaction.commit()` at end of the looped code. Thank you a lot :)